# Any way to capture fusion charts?

Tags: c#, javascript, fusioncharts

Here i am trying to capture fusion charts as images on a button click using javascript.
Here is my javascript code:

```
var initiateExport = false;

        function exportCharts() {
            var exportFormat = 'JPG';
            initiateExport = true;
            for (var chartRef in FusionCharts.items) {
                if (FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart) {
                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Exporting...";
                    FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart({ "exportFormat": exportFormat });

                }
                else {

                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Please wait till the chart completes rendering...";
                }
            }
        }

        function FC_Exported(statusObj) {
            if (initiateExport) {
                initiateExport = false;
                document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "";
            }

            if (statusObj.statusCode == "1") {

                document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML += "Export successful. View it from <a target='_blank' href='" + statusObj.fileName + "'>here</a>.<br/>";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML += "Export unsuccessful. Notice from export handler : " + statusObj.notice + "<br/>";

            }
        }
```

The problem with this is before image capture a progress bar comes showing "capturing data".I want to bypass that(as i have another code waiting for its completion) so that directly on button click the images are generated.If its not possible through javascript can someone suggest a method using **c#** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, these Flash charts need some time to complete capturing of image data from the flash display of the chart. It can not be done in an instance.

That is why the progress bar comes which indicates the progress of image data capturing.

You can hide the progress bar setting `showExportDialog="0"` in the XML for the chart. However, the internal progress will continue.

Once the image capture is complete, Flash POSTs the data to a Server Side Script (Export Handler) if you are using Server Side exporting.

If you are using Client Side exporting feature, the Flash chart raises an event named FC_ExportDataReady. You can listen to this event defining a function with the same name in window/global scope. This event provides the image data (stream) as a JavaScript Object. The stream object contains the image data in RLE format with meta data for the images.

Accordingly, it is not possible to generate the image snap of a chart instantly using a button click. It would take some time.

That is the reason why the FC_Exported calback event is provide so that you can listen to this event and and get a confirmation of the completion and then carry on with your own code.